# How to find class name presentation for NSManagedObject type?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I simply trying to define the following static property:

```
extension NSManagedObject {
    class var className: String {
        String(describing: classForCoder())
    }
}
```

which gives the following result for subclasses of `NSManagedObject`: `Person`, `Career`:

```
let firstName = Person.className // "Person"
let secondName = Career.className // "Career"
```

Comment: And? Don't you want Person and Career as the results?

Comment: What do you want that's different from the results you already have?